# Determine the distribution that has all moments equal to $\mu$ where $ 0 < \mu < 1$

Tags: probability-distributions

Determine the distribution that has all moments equal to $\mu$ where $ 0 < \mu < 1$

> Having difficulty getting started on this, any help appreciated.

Comment: Raw moments? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliDistribution.html

Comment: To get started you can calculate its MGF from the information given. (You should indeed get the MGF of the Bernoulli)

Comment: That's done it, thank you both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that, in order for the above to be true, we require that, for the distribution's moment generating function
$$
\partial_t^nf(t)\bigg|_{t=0} = \mu
$$
a simple guess for what this function should be yields
$$
f(t) = \mu e^t + C
$$
for some arbitrary constant $C$ (this is, in fact, the only analytic function which satisfies the above equality, which can be seen from assuming that $f$ is written as a power series).

Note that this is only true (in the distribution case) whenever we have a probability 'density' (I use this loosely) of the form
$$
p(x) = \mu\, \delta(x-1) + (1-\mu)\delta(x-0)
$$
which is exactly the Bernoulli distribution.

Comment: One may also note the reason that $\mu < 1$ is required. Indeed, as long as $\mu <1$ the unknown distribution must have an exponential moment, and thus its MGF is is defined and analytic on a nonempty interval of the origin.

Comment: So, how to rigorously prove "Note that this is only true (in the distribution case) whenever we have a probability 'density' (I use this loosely) of the form"?

Comment: @Jethro: For $f(t)$ to be a moment generating function, you need $f(0)=1$ and so $C=1-\mu$, i.e. $f(t)=\mu e^t +1-\mu$, which is indeed the mgf of a Bernoulli random variable with parameter (probability or mean) of $\mu$.  For the uniqueness issue, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458680/how-to-prove-moment-generating-function-uniqueness-theorem