# Does there exist a probability distribution such that all central moments are equal?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, moment-problem

I find [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3525/when-are-probability-distributions-completely-determined-by-their-moments) that if the moment generating function of a random variable has positive radius of convergence, then that random variable is determined by its moments. So does there exist a continuous probability distribution on $\mathbb R$ such that all of its moments are equal?

It is a bit tricky because saying that random variable is determined by its moments is not the same as saying that given any sequence of moments a random variable can be found.

Comment: Moments (as in the body of your question) or central moments (as in the title)?

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2404117/578053