# moment generating function uniquely determines distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

Suppose that X and Y are random variables both taking possible values in {$0, 1, 2 ...$}.
Further, suppose that X and Y have the same mgf for all t around $0$:
Then it holds:
$$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}e^{tj}f_X(j)-\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}e^{tj}f_Y(j)=0$$

$$\Rightarrow\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}e^{tj}[f_X(j)-f_Y(j)]=0$$
$$\Rightarrow \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}e^{tj}c_j=0 $$
with $c_j:=f_X(j)-f_Y(j)$.

Is there a way to justify that  $c_j=0$  for all $j \in \{0,1,...\}$

Answer (score 1):

First, notice that from the definition if $c_j$ we have $-1 \le c_j \le 1$ for all $j$.  Now suppose $c_0 \ne 0$, and WLOG $c_0 > 0$.  Then we have

\begin{align*}
0 &= \sum_{j=0}^\infty e^{tj}c_j = c_0 + \sum_{j=1}^\infty e^{tj}c_j
\end{align*}

so $c_0 = -\sum_{j=1}^\infty e^{tj}c_j$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.  Since each $c_j$ is at least $-1$ this implies $$ 0 < c_0 \le \sum_{j=1}^\infty e^{tj} = \sum_{j=1}^\infty (e^t)^j,$$

but this is a geometric series and can be made arbitrarily small by choosing $t \ll 0$.  This implies $c_0 = 0$, and we can use the same reasoning to show that $c_j = 0$ for all $j$ with induction.

Comment: Why does the last step imply that $c_0=0$ . THe value of the geoemtric series is still >0

Comment: If I consider mgf in an small intervall around 0, then argument would not hold?

Comment: Yes, that is correct: this argument will not work if we only have that their mgfs are only defined near $0$.

Comment: Is there another way to make this work around 0?

Comment: Yes, but it is no longer an easy proof: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458680/how-to-prove-moment-generating-function-uniqueness-theorem?rq=1

Comment: https://www.lewiswalsh.net/blog/uniqueness-of-moment-generating-functions

Comment: What do you think. How does he get to this derivative in the end. I think it is wrong.

Comment: It's not exactly wrong, he's just replacing $e^t$ with $x$, which is fine since the range of $e^t$ is $[0,\infty)$.  The issue is the same as the issue with my proof: it requires sending $t$ to $-\infty$ to get that the derivative formula holds at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The series $g(z) = \mathbb E[z^X] = \sum_{j=0}^\infty z^j f_X(j)$ converges
absolutely to an analytic function for $|z| < 1$, and the coefficients $f_X(j)$ can be obtainethbbd from the values of $g$ and its derivatives at $z=0$:

$$ f_X(j) = \frac{g^{(j)}(0)}{j!} $$

$g(z)$ for $z \ne 0$ can be obtained from the moment generating function:
$$ g(e^{-t}) = \mathbb E[e^{-tX}] = \sum_{j=0}^\infty e^{-tj} f_X(j)$$

So the moment generating function determines $g$, and that determines the distribution.

Comment: Thank you, but could I not go on with my proof and argue why $c_j$=0?