# How to get this result of integral?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

Statement

\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb R} \exp \left( -2\pi (\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})^2 \right) \exp\left( -i2 \pi \frac {x}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot f \right) dx 
= \exp \left( -\pi f^{2} / 2 \right)
\end{equation}

### My attempt based on J.G.'s tips

Call the integral I(f).

\begin{equation}
I(f) = \int_{\mathbb R} \left( -\pi x^{2} - i \sqrt{2} \pi x f \right) dx
\end{equation}

Integration by parts: $dv = dx$, $u = I(f)$, $v = x$, and $du = \delta I / \delta f$ so

\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb R} u dv = I(f) \cdot x - \int_{\mathbb R} x \frac{\delta I}{\delta f}
\end{equation}

---

How can you get the second power in the final result in the integration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are computing here the Fourier transform of a Gaussian. It is a basic fact of Fourier theory that the result is again a Gaussian, appearing as a function of the "frequency variable". This can be proven using residue calculus, or applying Green's theorem to a suitable setup in ${\mathbb R}^2$. In this way one obtains, e.g.,
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/2}\>\cos(\lambda x)\>dx=\sqrt{2\pi}\>e^{-\lambda^2/2}\ .$$
The rest is symmetry and scaling variables.

Comment: You are right! $\exp\left( -i2 \pi \frac {x}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot f \right) = cos(...)$ because odd and sine of the complex part reduces to zero, since odd.

Answer (score 1):

Call this integral $I\left( f\right)$ so $I\left( 0\right)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\exp\left(-\pi x^2\right)=1$ and $$\frac{\partial I}{\partial f}=-i\pi\sqrt{2}\int_\mathbb{R}x \exp\left(-\pi x^2-i\pi\sqrt{2}fx\right)dx.$$Rewrite $I,\,\frac{\partial I}{\partial f}$ using $x = y - \frac{if}{\sqrt{2}}$ to prove that $\frac{\partial I}{\partial f} = -\pi fI$. (You'll need to use integration by parts. If you get stuck, try emulating the method of the top answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86041/characteristic-function-of-a-standard-normal-random-variable).) Thus $I = \exp\left(-\tfrac{\pi f^2}{2}\right)$.

Comment: I  am thinking if $I'(f) = f I(f)$ here. How are you getting $I'(f) = f \int x (orig) dx$, particularly the new $x$ inside the integral on the right-hand-side?

Comment: @Masi You must have a sign error somewhere. I recommend you write $I,\,\frac{\partial I}{\partial f}$ as real numbers, as my link does. (In both cases the imaginary part is an odd function that integrates to 0.) Then $\frac{\partial I}{\partial f}$ is the integral of $uv'$ where, up to multiplicative constants, $u = \sin \pi\sqrt{2}fx,\,v = \exp\left(-\pi x^2\right)$.