# integration involving imaginary terms

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How do we integrate forms of following type with imaginary terms involved? Can we get a closed form of it  as result?

$\int-\frac{1}{4}(e^{-ix}-e^{ix})^2e^{\frac{4i(e^{-ix}-e^{ix})}{(e^{-ix}+e^{ix})^2}} \ dx \tag1$

Comment: take $e^{ix}=cosx + isinx$ and $e^{-ix}=cosx - isinx$ and then try to solve.

Comment: Your recent question really make me wonder where you find them.

Comment: The integrand is Real.

Comment: @UserX. Once I asked here if there a limit of the imagination of the textbooks, teachers, professors ... No answers, so I suppose that it is close to $\infty$

Comment: @Macavity only if you assume $\Im(x)=0$. Then the integrand is $\sin^2(x) e^{2 \tan(x) \sec(x)}$

Comment: @UserX The integrand can be written as $\int\sin^2xe^{2\tan{x}\sec{x}}$ even if $x$ is complex. The relations hold in general.

Comment: @DavidH In that case there is nevertheless no reason to assume the integrand to be real. But it seems natural to assume the integration to be over the real axis.

Comment: @DavidH   Actually I came back this equation (1) from the trig form you mentioned .Because I couldn't find a proper form. Then I turned in to imaginary stuff..The trig form u mentioned cant be reduced to a closed form. In this group there are  other approaches regarding imaginary integration [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85940/how-do-you-integrate-imaginary-numbers)   ..I am just thinking in that way.. Checking other stuffs like [this](http://www.mathnotes.org/?pid=109#?pid=109) too for getting some grip on complex integration

Comment: @UserX  I came to this form from a trig function which I couldnot reduce to a proper form. I had mentioned in my previous reply . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$\int-\dfrac{1}{4}(e^{-ix}-e^{ix})^2e^\frac{4i(e^{-ix}-e^{ix})}{(e^{-ix}+e^{ix})^2}~dx$

$=\int(\sin^2x)e^{2\sec x\tan x}~dx$

$=\int(1-\cos^2x)\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{4^n\sec^{2n}x\tan^{2n}x}{(2n)!}dx+\int(1-\cos^2x)\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{2^{2n+1}\sec^{2n+1}x\tan^{2n+1}x}{(2n+1)!}dx$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{4^n\sec^{2n}x\tan^{2n}x}{(2n)!}dx-\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{4^n\sec^{2n-2}x\tan^{2n}x}{(2n)!}dx+\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{2^{2n+1}\sec^{2n+1}x\tan^{2n+1}x}{(2n+1)!}dx-\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{2^{2n+1}\sec^{2n-1}x\tan^{2n+1}x}{(2n+1)!}dx$

$=\int dx+\int\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{4^n\sec^{2n}x\tan^{2n}x}{(2n)!}dx-\int\cos^2x~dx-2\int\tan^2x~dx-\int\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\dfrac{4^n\sec^{2n-2}x\tan^{2n}x}{(2n)!}dx+\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{2^{2n+1}\sec^{2n+1}x\tan^{2n+1}x}{(2n+1)!}dx-\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{2^{2n+1}\sec^{2n-1}x\tan^{2n+1}x}{(2n+1)!}dx$

$=\int\sin^2x~dx-2\int\tan^2x~dx+\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{4^{n+1}\sec^{2n+2}x\tan^{2n+2}x}{(2n+2)!}dx-\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{4^{n+2}\sec^{2n+2}x\tan^{2n+4}x}{(2n+4)!}dx+\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{2^{2n+1}\sec^{2n+1}x\tan^{2n+1}x}{(2n+1)!}dx-\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{2^{2n+1}\sec^{2n-1}x\tan^{2n+1}x}{(2n+1)!}dx$

$=\int\dfrac{1-\cos2x}{2}dx-2\int(\sec^2x-1)~dx+\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{4^{n+1}\sec^{2n}x\tan^{2n+2}x}{(2n+2)!}d(\tan x)-\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{4^{n+2}\sec^{2n}x\tan^{2n+4}x}{(2n+4)!}d(\tan x)+\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{2^{2n+1}\sec^{2n}x\tan^{2n}x}{(2n+1)!}d(\sec x)-\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{2^{2n+1}\sec^{2n-2}x\tan^{2n}x}{(2n+1)!}d(\sec x)$

$=\int\dfrac{3}{2}dx-\int\dfrac{\cos2x}{2}dx-2\int\sec^2x~dx+\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{4^{n+1}(1+\tan^2x)^n\tan^{2n+2}x}{(2n+2)!}d(\tan x)-\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{4^{n+2}(1+\tan^2x)^n\tan^{2n+4}x}{(2n+4)!}d(\tan x)+\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{2^{2n+1}(\sec^2x-1)^n\sec^{2n}x}{(2n+1)!}d(\sec x)-\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{2^{2n+1}(\sec^2x-1)^n\sec^{2n-2}x}{(2n+1)!}d(\sec x)$

$=\int\dfrac{3}{2}dx-\int\dfrac{\cos2x}{2}dx-2\int\sec^2x~dx+\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{4^{n+1}C_k^n\tan^{2k}x\tan^{2n+2}x}{(2n+2)!}d(\tan x)-\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{4^{n+2}C_k^n\tan^{2k}x\tan^{2n+4}x}{(2n+4)!}d(\tan x)+\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{2^{2n+1}C_k^n(-1)^{n-k}\sec^{2k}x\sec^{2n}x}{(2n+1)!}d(\sec x)-\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{2^{2n+1}C_k^n(-1)^{n-k}\sec^{2k}x\sec^{2n-2}x}{(2n+1)!}d(\sec x)$

$=\int\dfrac{3}{2}dx-\int\dfrac{\cos2x}{2}dx-2\int\sec^2x~dx+\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{4^{n+1}n!\tan^{2n+2k+2}x}{(2n+2)!k!(n-k)!}d(\tan x)-\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{4^{n+2}n!\tan^{2n+2k+4}x}{(2n+4)!k!(n-k)!}d(\tan x)+\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^{n-k}2^{2n+1}\sec^{2n+2k}x}{(2n+1)!k!(n-k)!}d(\sec x)-\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^{n-k}2^{2n+1}\sec^{2n+2k-2}x}{(2n+1)!k!(n-k)!}d(\sec x)$

$=\dfrac{3x}{2}-\dfrac{\sin2x}{4}-2\tan x+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{4^{n+1}n!\tan^{2n+2k+3}x}{(2n+2)!k!(n-k)!(2n+2k+3)}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{4^{n+2}n!\tan^{2n+2k+5}x}{(2n+4)!k!(n-k)!(2n+2k+5)}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^{n-k}2^{2n+1}n!\sec^{2n+2k+1}x}{(2n+1)!k!(n-k)!(2n+2k+1)}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^{n-k}2^{2n+1}n!\sec^{2n+2k-1}x}{(2n+1)!k!(n-k)!(2n+2k-1)}+C$