# Integration of complex numbers

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I was solving some integration questions, then one question arised in my mind that "Do the integration of complex no. possible?" 
If yes, then what is $\int i dx$? 
Definite integration is the area under curve of the graph but the above graph cannot be plotted on real plane. 
I want someone to please clear my doubts regarding integration. Thanks!!!

Comment: $i$ is a constant, so it can be moved outside of the integral.

Comment: answer is $=ix+C$

Comment: And what about definite integration.

Comment: @haqnatural Is $C \in \mathbb{C}$ or is $C\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: In general for continuous functions $\int_{a}^b u(x)+iv(x)=\int_{a}^b u(x)+i\int_{a}^b v(x)$.Also haqnatural but $(ix+5i)'=i$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you integrate imaginary numbers?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85940/how-do-you-integrate-imaginary-numbers)

Comment: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2016/09/27/246a-notes-2-complex-integration/

Comment: If the function has a complex derivative and is defined on the entire complex plane, then it has an antiderivative that's also defined on the entire complex plane. All polynomials have antiderivatives, for example. However, $\frac1x$ (which has a complex derivative, $-\frac1{x^2}$, but isn't defined at $x=0$) does not have an antiderivative defined everywhere (ignoring zero). It does have what are called "local antiderivatives," though.

Comment: Did you see an answer you would accept?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that $i$ is a constant, so $\int i \,dx = i x + C$

The more complete answer is that "area under curve of the graph" doesn't really make sense for what you are doing when you say $\int i \,dx$, you can integrate a complex variable $z=x +iy$ over a contour. I would check out [contour integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration) here, it might explain things a little better.