# De Moivre Complex Roots: Definition of $i$ or $\sqrt {-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Does $\sqrt{-1}=\pm\sqrt{-1}$ since it has 2 solutions for roots? Note the link says there are two complex square roots for -1 which are $i$ and $-i$ https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit.

Comment: Yes, but avoid this notation. Fractionary exponents should be used only with positive real numbers.

Comment: @Bernard Why so? If we're dealing with complex functions/numbers there's no problem at all. Of course, a branch for the complex square root must be chosen, but *in any* case it has to be that way.

Comment: I appreciate the response Bernard. Put it in the answer next time so I can give you credit!

Comment: Of course, when one knows well complex function theory (for example, DonAntonio mentions a "branch of the function square root"), but if the O.P. is a newcomer in the field $\mathbb C$ :), I do think as Bernard that it is a misleading notation that should be short-circuited by speaking about the two roots of equation $z^2=-1=e^{i\pi}$, i.e. $\pm e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}=\pm i.$

Comment: @JeanMarie You have a point there, yet I think it is one of the first things students are said when learning for the first time complex numbers: there nis **no** order as in the real numbers, and then I think the confussion between *positive or negative* root is moot.

Comment: @DonAntonio I understand your point : $\{i,-i\}$ is a kind of "package" with no one discernable from the other. It's almost quantic...

Comment: I don't think it is correct. Do you mean $i=\pm i$?

Comment: IMO, the above is abuse of notation.  As @msm mentions, it implies that $i=-i$, which is false.  Rather, it is better to say that $\sqrt{-1}=i$ and $\pm i$ are the solutions to $x^2=-1$.  When you state $x^2=-1$, it is much more clear what you are doing.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/13801/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your notation is $$i=\pm i$$ which implies $$i=-i \Rightarrow i=0$$ which is wrong.

Your confusion is probably from 
$$z^2=-1=e^{\pm i\pi}\Rightarrow z=e^{\pm i\pi/2}=0+i \sin(\pm \pi/2)=\pm i$$
But in the above equation $+i$ and $-i$ are two **distinct** solutions of the equation. They are not equal. However, they are two square roots of $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\sqrt{-1} = -\sqrt{-1}$, then $$\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{\sqrt{-1}} = -1.$$ But,
$$ \frac{\sqrt{-1}}{\sqrt{-1}} =1.$$ So $1=-1$, a clear contradiction.