# Complex Numbers, Understanding Square Roots

Tags: complex-numbers

Since $i^2 = -1$, then doesn't $i = \pm \sqrt[2]{i}$? How does $i$ only equal the plus part?

Comment: We don't need to know what $i$ is, $i^2$ is enough.

Comment: You are asking the same question as yesterday in (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1955626) ! It is not a good practise. I ask to close this one.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/13801/321264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually $\pm i=\sqrt {-1}$, not $i=\pm \sqrt {-1}$.

For any complex number $z$ and any positive integer $n$, $z^{1/n}$ has $n$ distinct values in the set of complex numbers. e.g. $1^{1/3}$ has three distinct values : $1,\omega,\omega^2.$ Similarly $(-1)^{1/2}$ must also have two distinct values, $i$ and $-i.$ For an imaginary number, it is meaningless to say it is positive or negative, so you cannot say " $i=\sqrt {-1}$, taking the positive square root" (as we normally do for the square root of a positive real number).

By a **pure convention** one may write $i = \sqrt{-1}$, but this convention is not logically tenable from various considerations, and mathematically there is no need for such a convention. The symbol $i$ standing for the unique complex number $(0,1)$ and understood by $i^2=-1$ is good enough for any mathematical purpose.

Comment: Really good information. I know the question seems wicked basic. However, sometimes it's not how far ahead you go in math, but how far back you can go to the basics that shows your knowledge in the subject. This answer clearly shows that.

Answer (score 2):

We cannot say $i = \pm \sqrt[2]{-1}$ without first defining $\sqrt[2]{-1}$. It's true that if you have a number $a$ such that $a^2 = -1$, then $b^2 = -1$ for $b=-a$. Whether we choose to give $a$ the name $i$ (and then $b=-i$) or give $b$ the name $i$ (then $a = -i$) is arbitrary and the mathematics that ensue are equivalent.