# Why does calculator say that $\sqrt{4} = 2$?

Tags: roots, calculator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Square roots — positive and negative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26363/square-roots-positive-and-negative)

I know that the square roots of four are

- 2 because $2^2=4$
- and $-2$ because $(-2)^2=4$

Are there any conventions in considering primarily the positive square root or adding the $\pm$ symbol in the calculator screen would be a cost factor?

Comment: There might be even better duplicates, but this one seems adequate.

Comment: By definition the symbol $\sqrt{x}$ denotes the non-negative square root of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

The very same question could also apply to other functions (e.g. trigonometric functions). SQRT is defined as returning only the +ve value of the square root. Check here for a thorough discussion on this topic: http://forums.randi.org/archive/index.php/t-36241.html.

Comment: If by "thorough" you mean "long and full of misconseptions", then by all means it's thorough.