# Why sqrt(4) isn't equall to-2?

Tags: arithmetic, radicals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Square roots — positive and negative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26363/square-roots-positive-and-negative)

$\sqrt{4} = -2$. WolframAlpha says "false"!

Now lets take a deeper look to my idea.

Well...we know that,

$$2^2 = 4 \iff \sqrt{4} = 2$$

$(-2)^2 = 4$ so why can't $\sqrt{4}$ be equal to $-2$?

I'm a little bit confused

// Thank you for all your answers, I have answer now. Stepo

Comment: There are indeed two numbers that square to 4 but we have to choose which we meen by the square root. We usually choose the positive one.

Comment: $-2$ is **a** square root of four. $2$ is **the** square root of four (which is what that symbol means).

Comment: @user2838619, the [tag:roots] tag isn't relevant for questions about square roots or other radicals.  Use [tag:radicals] instead.

Comment: Just a quick supplement to the answers you got - it may help to think about $\sqrt{x}$ as the side length of a square with area $x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By definition, $$\sqrt{x^2} = \vert x \vert$$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: That's more like the definition of absolute value, which is based on the fact that $\sqrt{x}$ will always return a positive value.

Comment: @Graphth The definition of $\vert \cdot \vert$, I use is $$\vert x \vert = \begin{cases} x & \text{if } x\geq0 \\ -x & \text{if } x < 0\end{cases}$$

Comment: In reality, we know what a square root is before we define $\sqrt{}$, and so we define that symbol to mean the positive square root.  But, I've never seen any one define what $\sqrt{}$ means by $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$.  I guess it's just a more complicated way of saying the same thing.  Since your reputation is 7 times mine, I will defer to you :)

Answer (score 5):

It's just notation most likely.  Yes, $(-2)^2 = 4$, but often the $\sqrt{4}$ symbol is reserved for the positive square root, so $\sqrt{4} = 2$.  If you want the negative square root, that would be $-\sqrt{4} = -2$.  Both $-2$ and $2$ are square roots of $4$, but the notation $\sqrt{4}$ corresponds to only the positive square root.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that $(-2)^2 = 4$.

The idea is that we want $\sqrt{x}$ to be a continuous, single valued function. But as you noted there are two possibile values of $\sqrt{x}$ for each $x$, so we have to choose a particular branch and that is what we call $\sqrt{x}$.

So the standard choice is to just take positive $\sqrt{x}$ for every $x$.