# What do you mean by root(x)?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, boolean-algebra

What do you mean by $\operatorname{root}(x)$ ?

What's the value of $\operatorname{root}(252+ \operatorname{root}(8+ root(64$))) ?

Is it $+16$ or $+ 16$ and $-16$ ?

I have seen Wikipedia.

It is given that :
$\operatorname{root}(x^2) = \operatorname{mod}(x)$ where $x$ can be $-ve$ or $+ve$.

Here ,
$\operatorname{root}(256) = \operatorname{mod}(16) = \operatorname{mod}(-16) = 16$

Am I right??

Comment: What is the Wikipedia page that you refer to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Square roots -- positive and negative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26363/square-roots-positive-and-negative)

Comment: @AnujGupta Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

In general, the $n$th root of a number $a$ refers to the solutions of the equation
$$\tag{1}
x^n = a
$$
In particular, the square root, which is the second root, is a solution to the equation
$$
x^2 = a
$$
Without any additional modifiers, the word *root* of a number refers to this square root. For example, the root of $256$ can be thought of as the solution to the equation
$$
x^2 = 256
$$
It's fairly easy to see that this has the solutions $16$ and $-16$. 
But if you're using a calculator (be it a pocket calculator or a computer), normally a calculator doesn't know how to list all the solutions. In calculators, the root is calculated by 
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
x = \sqrt[n]{a}
\end{equation}
And the square root is again same as $n=2$. The difference between Equations (1) and (2) is that the result of the calculation in the second equation is either always positive (if $n$ is even) or takes the sign of $a$ (if $n$ is odd). Therefore, if you ask a calculator, the root of $256$ is $\sqrt{256} = 16$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition for $a\ge0$ we have $\sqrt a =b\ge 0$ such that $b^2=a$.

Then when we consider the case $\sqrt {x^2}$ we have two cases

- $x\ge 0\implies \sqrt x^2=x$
- $x< 0\implies \sqrt x^2=-x$

that is

- $ \sqrt {x^2}=|x|$