# Why is $|x| \leq \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ for all real $x$ and $y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. From the triangle inequality, we have $$||(x, y)|| \leq ||(x, 0)|| + ||(y, 0)||$$ which means that $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq \sqrt{x^2} + \sqrt{y^2} = x+y.$$

Whether or not that's relevant, I'd like to conclude that $$|x| \leq \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$$ for all real $x$ and  $y$, and [Wolfram Alpha says that I can](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=abs(x)%20%3C%20sqrt(x%5E2%2By%5E2)); but, I don't see how to do this. Could someone please show why this last inequality is true for all real $x$ and $y$?

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le x+y$ is false when $x$ and $y$ are negative.

Comment: Because $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}\leq\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic But isn't $\sqrt{x^2} = \pm x \neq |x|$?

Comment: I don’t know why so many people don’t know what the symbol $\sqrt{\,}$ means. The idea that $\sqrt{x^2}=\pm x$ is complete **nonsense**: the symbol $\sqrt{x^2}$ **refers to a number** and **of course** a number can’t equal *both* $x$ and $-x$ (when $x$ is nonzero). The symbol means “take the **nonnegative** square root.” It **never makes any sense** to write $a=\pm 2$, no matter what you take $a$ to be. Don’t ever write “something$=\pm$ something” again!

Comment: @sawghol: See [Square roots -- positive and negative](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/26363/856)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x,y \in \mathbb{R}$

1)$|x|=\sqrt{x^2};$

2) $x^2 \le x^2+y^2$, since $y^2 \ge 0.$

3) Square root is an increasing function.

Hence

4)$ |x| \le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$

Answer (score 1):

Use $y^2\ge0$ to conclude that $x^2\le x^2+y^2$ and then take square roots.