# Test Prep Question: square root equation equal to negative number

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a solution for this equation? Please verify my answer and work for this question. I think the answer is **D**.

If $\sqrt{5x-9} = -4$, then x = ?

Options are
A) 1
B) 2.2
C) 5
D) No solution

The way I solved this problem is by squaring both sides to get rid of the square root. Then I just solve as a regular equation.

$$\sqrt{5x-9} = -4$$
$$(\sqrt{5x-9})^2 = (-4)^2$$
$$5x-9 = 16$$
$$5x   = 25$$
$$x = 5$$

I get $x=5$ so would the answer be C but when I plug $x=5$ into the original equation I get a false statement. That's why I would choose D.

$\sqrt{5(4)-9} = -4$
$\sqrt{16} = -4$
$4 = -4$  False statement

Thanks in advance. I hope I formatted the math statements correctly.

Comment: You're right, but square roots are never negative, so we can immediately see that the answer is D.

Comment: Trick question...

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/26369/305759