# Prove that if $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ are positive, then $a \leq b$ implies $\sqrt a \leq \sqrt b$.

Tags: real-numbers, radicals

Prove that if $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ are positive, then $a \leq b$ implies $\sqrt a \leq \sqrt b$.

I have seen proof for this problem at a couple of places. People have used the property $0 \leq a-b = (\sqrt a + \sqrt b)(\sqrt a - \sqrt b)$ and dividing this by $(\sqrt a + \sqrt b)$ gets the result. But I don't think this is the right proof because if even though $a,b$ are positive but square roots of positive numbers could be negative. So, $(\sqrt a + \sqrt b) $ could be negative as well. So, dividing by $(\sqrt a + \sqrt b)$ could also lead to $\sqrt a \geq \sqrt b $. Am I missing something here?

Comment: The  square root of a positive number is positive !

Comment: By convention, the notation $\sqrt{x}$ usually denotes the nonnegative square root.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26363/square-roots-positive-and-negative

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt{x}) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$. For $x>0$ this is positive so the square root function is always increasing, so this is simply the definition of increasing. Increasing functions always preserve the inequality while decreasing ones reverse it.

Answer (score 1):

You are right since by your hipothesis $a,b> 0$ and $b-a> 0$ but
$b-a=(\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a})(\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{a})> 0$ and now the square root of a positive number is positive and then $(\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{a})\neq 0$ as well
and hence $\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a}> 0$ wich complete the proof.

Notice that if $a=b=0$ the inequality holds.