# Does the input-output relation definition hold for radical functions?

Tags: functions, definition, radicals

For example, I have a function, $f\left(x\right)=\sqrt{x}$ where, x >= 0. For an input of x = 4 for example, the square root would be ±2.

Does that not mean there are two answers/outputs, **2 and -2**?

But the definition of a function states that **every input has exactly one output**.

Please tell me what I am missing here.
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is sqrt(x) a function? Does it matter if a domain is given?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53410/is-sqrtx-a-function-does-it-matter-if-a-domain-is-given)

Comment: You defined the function to be $f(x)=\sqrt x$, not  $f(x)=-\sqrt x$ or some other thing.

Comment: For positive real $x$, the symbol $\sqrt{x}$ always represents the positive square root.