# Is there an application to NOT assuming that a square root is positive?

Tags: roots, real-numbers

Further to the question here:[Why is the even root of a number always positive?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41878/why-is-the-even-root-of-a-number-always-positive)
If it is mere "convention" (agreement) that we use positive real numbers as the even-powered-roots of positive real numbers then this begs further questions.

Does making this assumption ever get mathematicians into trouble or prevent them from getting results? Are there examples where you need to use Both the possible roots to fully solve a problem?