# Square roots: $ -\sqrt{a} = \sqrt{b}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

[CLOSED] Thanks 
GoodDeeds and Henry [1]
I understood the fundamental problem.

As **√9 = ± 3**

If , **√A = √B**
Thus, ** ±a =  ±b**
And so a = b; -a = b; and  a = -b;;
Thus, **√9 = +3 OR -3**

Let, **√A = ±a**
and, **√B = ±b**
Is this reasoning correct?

If not how does this actually work?

[1] \bib{26369}{misc}{
    title={Square roots -- positive and negative},
    author={Henry (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6460/henry)},
    note={URL: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/26369 (version: 2011-03-11)},
    eprint={https://math.stackexchange.com/q/26369},
    organization={Mathematics Stack Exchange}
}

Comment: The square root is a function, hence $\sqrt{9}=3$ and not $\pm 3$ at the same time.

Comment: Also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41878/why-is-the-even-root-of-a-number-always-positive

Comment: This question is different from the "duplicate". In particular it involves the interpretation of the statement $\pm a=\pm b$ and the conclusions that can be drawn from it in the frame of multivalued square roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The mistake is that $\sqrt{9}\ne\pm3$, $\sqrt{9}=+3$ only.

This is because the square root function is defined such that only the non negative root is taken. In general,
$$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$$

Moreover, your reasoning will lead to absurd conclusions, such as $$\sqrt{9}=\sqrt{9}$$
$$+3=-3$$
which is obviously not true.

Answer (score 2):

> As √9 = ± 3

[No, the square root function is always $\ge 0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26363/square-roots-positive-and-negative)

> Thus, √9 = +3 OR -3

[No, the square root function is always $\ge 0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26363/square-roots-positive-and-negative)

> Let, √A = ±a
>   and, √B = ±b

[No, the square root function is always $\ge 0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26363/square-roots-positive-and-negative)

> If , √A = √B
>   Thus, ** ±a = ±b**
>   And so a = b; -a = b; and a = -b;;
>
> Is this reasoning correct?

[The reasoning is not correct because the square root function is always $\ge 0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26363/square-roots-positive-and-negative)

> If not how does this actually work?

[The square root function is always $\ge 0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26363/square-roots-positive-and-negative)

Comment: Minor nitpick: the square root of zero is not positive.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the square root of $x \in \mathbb{R}, x \geq 0$ is the only positive number $y \in \mathbb{R}, y \geq 0$ such taht $y^2=x$.

Your reasoning works with a different definition of the square root, which is a function $yoursqrt : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 $