# roots: square roots, cube roots, x^1/4, x^1/5

Tags: radicals

I was having confusion over the concepts of roots. My confusion begins as:
I know that if $x^{1/n}=y$ then $y^n=x$ must be true.

**Case 1:** With square roots, let's take $y=4^{1/2}$

We know $y=2$ is a solution as $2^2=4$, but $y=-2$ must also be a solution as $(-2)^2=4$ is also true. But I browsing here I read that $(x^2)^{1/2}$ is actually equivalent to absolute value of $x$, hence only $y=2$ is solution of my above case.

**Case 2:** With cubic root,
let's restrict ourselves to the real no.s's domain,
let's take $y=(-8)^{1/3}$, then $y=-2$ seems feasible solution as $(-2)^3=-8$ but why in this case absolute value after cube root is not required.
Also, why $(-x)^{1/3}=-(x)^{1/3}$, but $(-x)^{1/2}$ is not equal to $-(x)^{1/2}$

The same apparent ambiguity goes with $x^{1/4}$ and $x^{1/5}$

So, in general what is the general function definition of $x^{1/n}$?

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Compare the phrases "**a** n'th root" vs "**the** n'th root."  If we refer to **the** root, it implies there is only one that we are interested in, and we generally take it to be the "[principal root](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/principal_root)."

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41878/why-is-the-even-root-of-a-number-always-positive/41882#41882)

Comment: note that $(-x)^2=x^2$ but $(-x)^3=-x^3$, and $2$ and $3$ can be replaced with other even and odd numbers, respectively

Answer (score 0):

In general a real or complex number has $n$, $n^{th}$ roots in complex numbers.

In case that you are interested in real roots if $n$ is odd there is only one $n^{th} $ root of the real number $x$ and it has  the same sign as $x$

On the other hand if $n$ is even the real number $x$ has two real $n^{th} $ roots one positive and one negative.

For example we have $\sqrt {25}=5$ and its opposite $-\sqrt {25}=-5$ as two real square roots of $25$

For $  x=-64$ there is only one real cube root and it is $-4$