# Square root of a number squared is equal to the absolute value of that number

Tags: radicals, absolute-value, convention

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Significance of $\displaystyle\sqrt[n]{a^n} $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13094/significance-of-displaystyle-sqrtnan)

The square root of a number squared is equal to the absolute value of that number.
Why is $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$? Why not just $x$? Please give me a reason and also help me prove it.

Comment: i have  studied in school that aritmetic root of any number is  such non negative number whose  square is  given number  so it means that we take  absolute sign to  ensure  square is not negative

Comment: It's basically because of convention. Since $a^2=(-a)^2$ for any $a$, there will always be two square roots of any positive number. We define the function $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ for positive $x$ to be the positive square root. So if $x$ is negative, then $\sqrt{x^2}$ is $x$ flipped across $0$ to the positive side, or $|x|$.

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2}$ couldn't possibly be plain $x$ in general.  If the square root function is given the number $4$, how can it *know* whether the $4$ came from $2^2$ or $(-2)^2$?

Comment: In your question you should say "real number" and not just "number".  It is false for complex numbers.  But at least $\sqrt{x^2}$ is either $x$ or $-x$.

Answer (score 5):

You are referring to the *principal square root*. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_square_root): "Although the principal square root of a positive number is only one of its two square roots, the designation 'the square root' is often used to refer to the principal square root."

Answer (score 1):

By definition the square root of a nonnegative real number $y$ is the unique real number $z$ for which $z\geq 0$ and $z^2=y$. Consequently, to prove that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ it is enough to show that $|x|\geq 0$ and $|x|^2=x^2$ but these two facts are very easy to verify.