# Square root of x

Tags: roots

How many values of $$\sqrt x$$ is possible. Is it 2 or 1?The graph says only one but why not 2 one is positive an the other is negative.[image]

Please explain why is it so?

But[image]
Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Lots of questions like this on  the site. Possuble duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59630/square-root-of-a-number-squared-is-equal-to-the-absolute-value-of-that-number

Comment: For $x > 0$ (and $x$ a real number) $\sqrt {x}$ is *ONE* of the two possible square roots.  By definition $\sqrt{x}$ is the *positive* square root.  $-\sqrt{x}$ is the negative one.  $\sqrt{x}$ is not *THE* square root of $x$.  It is the *POSITIVE* square root of $x$.

Comment: Another dupe [Square root confusion?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448885/square-root-confusion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $x\ge0$, $\sqrt{x}$ is defined as the non-negative square root of $x$, i.e. the non-negative real number $y$ such that $y^2=x$.

If we take both the positive and negative square roots of $x$ as $\sqrt{x}$, expressions like $\sqrt{4}+\sqrt{9}+\sqrt{16}$ can mean $2+3+4$, $2+3-4$, $2-3+4$, etc. Things become very complicated.

If $x\ge0$, the equation $y^2=x^2$ has two solutions $y=x$ and $y=-x$. Since $x$ is the non-negative one, $\sqrt{x^2}=x$.

If $x<0$, the equation $y^2=x^2$ has two solutions $y=x$ and $y=-x$. Since $-x$ is the non-negative one, $\sqrt{x^2}=-x$.

Therefore, $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$. That's why we have the V-shaped graph.

Answer (score 3):

The square root function $\sqrt{a}$ is defined as the non-negative solution of the equation $x^2-a=0$.

It is not the same as asking: What are the solutions of $x^2-a=0$? (Which in this case, the negative and positive solution are correct.)

You are viewing the square root function as the inverse function of $f(x)=x^2$. The function $f$ doesn't have an inverse function since it is not a bijection (a function $f$ such that every element $y$ of the codomain has a unique element $x$ in the domain that $f(x)=y$).

The function $f(x)=x^2$ is not a bijection if the domain is the real numbers but the square root function has been created by restricting the domain of $f$ to $[0,+\infty[$ to make it a bijection and finding the inverse of the function with the restricted domain.

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt{x}$ is *not* "THE" square root of $x$ because if $x > 0$ (and real) there are two square roots of $x$ and there is no "THE" square root of $x$.

$\sqrt{x}$ is *not* $\{y \in R| y^2 = x\}$.  That is a set that can have two values.  $\sqrt{}$ is a *function* that maps $\sqrt{}:[0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ so being a function $\sqrt{x}$ is one specific value.

So what *is* $\sqrt{x}$?  It is the function $\sqrt{x} =$  the **non-negative** square root of $x$.  That is its definition  It is *defined* to never be negative.

In other words, if $x > 0$ then there are *TWO* square roots $y$ and $w$ so that $y^2 = x$ and $w^2 = x$ and $y = -w$ or in other words *one* of them will be negative and the other one will be positive.  $\sqrt{x}$ is *ONE* of them; the *positive* one.  $-\sqrt{x}$ is the other negative one.

(And, of course, if $x = 0$ then there aren't two $y^2 = 0$ and $w^2 = 0$ and $y = -w$.  There is only *one* $y = w = 0$ and $0 = -0$ so that $y^2 = w^2 = 0$.  So $\sqrt {0} = -\sqrt{0} = 0$.)