# Why are the graph of $f(x) = (x^2)^\frac{1}{6}$ and the graph of $f(x) = x^\frac{1}{3}$ not the same?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions, exponentiation

Why is the graph of $f(x) = (x^2)^\frac{1}{6}$ not the same graph as $f(x) = x^\frac{1}{3}$?

Shouldn't they be the same because when you apply the exponent rules to the first equation, you get the same result as the second equation?

By the way, I am an Algebra 2 student in High School.

Comment: Hint-When you square something the negative disappears.

Comment: Exponent rules don't work with negative bases and fractional exponents; cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219025/why-22-5-isnt-equal-to-2251-10)

Comment: The short answer is that $(x^p)^q=x^{pq}$ only for $x>0$ when $p$ and $q$ are rational numbers.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2085268/does-i4-equal-1/2085269#2085269, and in particular the second-to-last paragraph.

Comment: Genuine question: is $-1^ \frac13$ where the operation " ^ $^ \frac13$ " is acting upon real numbers only and not in the complex realm, generally considered to be equal to $-1$, or is it undefined? Or do different texts have different conventions? Ah, J. W. Tanner has linked to the answer to my question...

Answer (score 5):

When you square the quantity $x$, the negative sign disappears, and it doesn't come back if you raise it to the $\frac{1}{6}$ power. If you just take $\frac{1}{3}$ power, then the negative stays negative.

$((-1)^2)^\frac{1}{6}=1^\frac{1}{6}=1$, while $(-1)^\frac{1}{3}=-1$

Therefore, what you see on the first graph is the absolute value of the second graph.

[This hyperlink](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lfnit8kelb) contains a graph of the two equations. Note that when $x<0$ the red solid line is the blue dotted line reflected about the x-axis.