# What is $\sqrt{x^2}$?

Tags: definition, real-numbers, radicals, square-numbers

At first the question of what $\sqrt{x^2}$ is seems silly. It looks like $x$. And for $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$ it is.

However, for $\mathbb{R}$, I'm not sure. I can think of 3 answers:

- $abs(x)$
- $\{x,-x\}$
- $x$

Which one is correct and why?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13094/significance-of-sqrtnan

Comment: The symbol $\sqrt{x}$ most often means the unique positive root of $x$, which allows $\sqrt{x}$ to be a single valued function. If this is the case, your expression takes the same (positive) value for $x^2$ and $(-x)^2$ so it is option 1. Alternatively, the symbol $\sqrt{x}$ sometimes (e.g., in some British educational systems) refers to *both* the positive and negative roots in which case you would have option 2. But really this should be written as $\pm \sqrt{x}$. There is no case where option 3 would be chosen, since this is arbitrarily choosing positive and negative square roots.

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt{x^2}=x$ for $x\geq0$ and $\sqrt{x^2}=-x$ for $x<0$, which says $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|.$

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt a$, for $a\in[0,\infty)$, is the non-negative real solution ofthe equation $x^2-a=0$. Therefore $\sqrt{t^2}=\lvert t\rvert$ for all $t\in\Bbb R$.