# Is this an inconsistency in the foundation of complex numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have always wondered this and apologize if I'm reposting, but I don't know how to find out the answer, also Im a little new to math but always liked it, and I'm learning and am starting out with complex analysis, so here goes. I believe:

$i={\sqrt {-1}} = {\sqrt {\frac{1}{-1}}} = {{\frac{\sqrt {1}}{\sqrt {-1}}}}=\frac{1}{i}$

But that gives you $i^2=1$ and not $-1$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: In $\Bbb C$, it is not true that $\sqrt{a/b}=\sqrt a/\sqrt b$. (In fact your question provides a proof of this fact!)

Comment: This one of the most popular duplicates. See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13801/whats-the-thing-with-sqrt-1-i?noredirect=1&lq=1), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13094/significance-of-sqrtnan#13103).